# Wildcard match using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have to extract file ID from file links. The file link is similar to this example "\abc.xyz\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder5 **\F-17-50021\OE** \abc\xyz\file.xlsm" (bold part remains the same in every link).
I decided to use regex to extract the file ID as there is a fixed pattern. I tried using the code below.

```
p = "Antartica"

re.search("n(.*)c",p).group(1)
```

It gives the output 'tarti' which is fine.
I created a same regex to extract the file ID but it's not working.

```
p = r"\\abc.xyz\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder5\F-17-50021\OE\abc\xyz\file.xlsm"

re.search('\(.*)\OE', p).group(1)
```

I'm getting an error in mentioning "*'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'*".

Please explain what is wrong in my code. How can I make it work?

TIA

Comment: There are no `"` in your input string.

Comment: I did that to accommodate the backslash inside the string. I will edit the post.

Comment: You are getting a `None` from `re.search(...)` this is the case when that doesn't find a pattern match. like @WiktorStribiżew stated you are looking for `"` characters in your pattern and they do not exist. Also consider using `os.path.split()` for a more robust cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
import re
 
p = r"\\abc.xyz\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder5\F-17-50021\OE\abc\xyz\file.xlsm"
match = re.search(r'\\([^\\]+)\\OE', p)
if match is not None:
    print(match.group(1))
```

See [Python proof](https://ideone.com/2ry2Sw).

**Results**: `F-17-50021`

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\\]+                   any character except: '\\' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  OE                       'OE'
```

Comment: this works! Could you please explain the regex a little?

Comment: @wickedpanda See **Explanation**

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryszard! :)

Comment: I just found that in some links "\OE" has been replaced by "\FLD" or "\TURN" . Is it possible to add all three in the regex like an "or" statement '\OE" or "FLD" or "\TURN"?

Comment: @wickedpanda Yes, `r'\\([^\\]+)\\(?:OE|FLD|TURN)'`

Comment: works like a charm!! Do you know of some place where I can learn similar regex tricks? Thanks again!

Comment: @wickedpanda  Have a look at the http://regular-expressions.info.